# NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath - how to use properly?

Tags: unity, navmesh

I seriously can't figure out how to use this function, and the documentation doesn't help at all.

Here's the documentation code:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
 public Transform target;
 private NavMeshAgent agent;
 void Start() {
     agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
     NavMeshPath path;
     agent.CalculatePath(target.position, path);
     if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathPartial) {
     }
   }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {
 NavMeshAgent agent;
 NavMeshPath path;

 void Start () {
     agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
 }

 void MoveToTargetLocation() {
     agent.SetDestination(targetLocation); <-- being set somewhere else

     NavMeshPath path;
     agent.CalculatePath (targetLocation, path);

     if (path.status != NavMeshPathStatus.PathPartial) {
         if (Vector3.Distance (curLocation, targetLocation) > 0.55) {
             animation.CrossFade (animationRun.name);
             moving = true;
         } else {
             animation.CrossFade (animationIdle.name);
             moving = false;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> Assets/Movement.cs(59,54): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local
>   variable `path'

Am I supposed to be setting the path somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the NavMesh. You've defined `path` at two different scopes. Look at your code for two instances of `NavMeshPath path;` Try removing the local instance and add `= new NavMeshPath();` to the other one.

I'm not sure why the documentation is the way it is. The method `CalculatePath` is clearly looking for an initialized `NavMeshPath` object. If it was to work as stated in their example, they'd need the `out` parameter option in the `CalculatePath` method to show that object will be initialized inside the method.

Comment: I fixed that. Still the same error.

Comment: @J.R. See update.

Comment: Now it gives me: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on line: `agent.CalculatePath (targetLocation, path);` So clearly I'm supposed to be setting the path variable somewhere?

Comment: You sure you have a `NavMeshAgent` component on the same object? I suspect that's where your NullReferenceException is coming from.

Comment: I fixed it. I had to add the `path = new NavMeshPath` to the start function. Thanks!